# Hitting an exception with custom webpack on Angular10

Tags: angular, webpack, angular8, angular10

With Angular10 upgrade, I am hitting an exception with the use of the custom webpack option (during the ng build --prod)

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/custom-webpack/package.json'
Require stack:
- node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/node-modules-architect-host.js
- node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/index.js
- node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js
- node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/build-impl.js
- node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/export-ref.js
- node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/index.js
- node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/json-schema.js
- node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js
- node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/cli/index.js
- node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/init.js
- node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
See "/private/var/folders/hg/q4kb7lqx1sg32v9bsylb004r0000gp/T/ng-EEYyRU/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

Here are my relevant dependencies in package.json

```
"dependencies": {

    "@angular/animations": "10.0.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "10.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "10.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "10.0.4",
    "@angular/core": "10.0.4",
    "@angular/forms": "10.0.4",
    "@angular/material": "10.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "10.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "10.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-server": "10.0.4",
    "@angular/router": "10.0.4",
},
devDependencies: {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "10.0.0",
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.1000.4",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "~0.1000.3",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^10.0.4",
    "@angular/cli": "10.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "10.0.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "10.0.4",
}
```

Any pointers on what could be going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Change in angular.json '@angular-devkit/custom-webpack/'. into '@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser'